# No sound coming from laptop, all HDMI and no analog

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

my built-in speaker sound seems to not be working. My sound hasn't worked since I switched to Ubuntu, and it has worked perfectly fine on Windows. When I first installed Ubuntu, my sound has defaulted to "Dummy Output". I looked up how to fix this on Google and one of the pages says i have to change the default sound device in PulseAudio's Config page. But that barely helped, as all of the profiles are HDMI and none are analog/built in speaker. Have a look for yourself:

Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output

Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output

Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output

Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output

Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output

Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output

Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output

Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output

Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output

Comment: What kind of audio device do you have (make/model)? Have you looked for drivers?  What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Nmath I have an Intel Atom processor with integrated sound. I saw a driver on the Intel website but it looks complicated as heck to set up. I'm using version 20.04.

Comment: To start with, which  release number is installed?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.